# How to calculate the recursive form of an explicit sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm in trouble with this questions.

$a_n=5^n$ where $n=1,2,3,...$

$a_1=5^1=5,\, a_2=5^2=25,\, a_3=5^3=125$

I always try to resolve such questions by using $a_n-a_{n-1}$ But this time I can't resolve it.

I know $a_n-a_{n-1}=5^n-5^{n-1}$. Here I can't continue. How to move on?

Comment: what about $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: $a_n - a_{n-1} = 5^{n-1}(5 - 1) = 4 a_{n-1}$, so $a_n = \dots$

Comment: @Alex: **user3313320** is suggesting that instead of $a_n-a_{n-1}$, in this case you should look at $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$; I agree.

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal So you mean $a_n= 4a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}?$ On the book say that equal  $a_{n+1}=5a_n$

Comment: @Alex: $a_n = 5a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n+1} = 5a_n$ are equivalent. Both express that each term is equal to five times the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=5^n=\underbrace{5\cdot5\cdot5\cdots5}_{n-times}$$

$$5^{n+1}=(\underbrace{5\cdot5\cdot5\cdots5}_{n-times})\cdot5$$
$$a_{n+1}=a_n\cdot5$$
$$a_n=5a_{n-1}$$